# Maximum Mean Discrepancy (MMD) implementation as a metric to measure GAN performance

Tags: machine-learning, probability, neural-networks, metric, generative-models

I am trying to evaluate the performance of the GAN model, I have trained. I found that there exist two major choices FID (Fréchet inception distance) and MMD (Maximum Mean Discrepancy) for comparing the similarity of the training set and generated set data distributions.
The nature of the data I have is coordinate points, in a plane with `(number_of_samples, number_of_points, 2)` shape.
Of the two choices, I felt that MMD is the most appropriate for the point kind of data while the other is good for the image kind of data. Also, I read that MMD possess better properties than FID from https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2401.09603

I see that MMD can be used as a loss function and/or as a metric to gauge the performance while training a GAN. In my case, I am interested in using it as a metric to measure GAN performance.

After going through the literature and a few implementations, I wrote the following piece of code. It is expected to evaluate MMD taking numpy arrays of the training set true data and generated synthetic data. I am not seeing any decreasing trend of MMD during training, despite of visibly increasing quality of synthetic data.

```py
import numpy as np

def mmd_rbf(true_ds: np.ndarray, synthetic_ds: np.ndarray, band_width=10.0):
    sd, td = synthetic_ds[:, -1], true_ds[:, -1]  # flattening non-batch dimensions
    xx = np.matmul(sd, sd.T)
    xy = np.matmul(sd, td.T)
    yy = np.matmul(td, td.T)
    # evaluate squared similarity matrices
    rx = np.tile(np.diag(xx)[None, ...], [xx.shape[0], 1])
    ry = np.tile(np.diag(yy)[None, ...], [yy.shape[0], 1])
    ssm_xx = rx - (2.0 * xx) + rx.T
    ssm_xy = ry - (2.0 * xy) + rx.T
    ssm_yy = ry - (2.0 * yy) + ry.T
    # Evaluate components of the MMD
    gamma = 1 / (2.0 * band_width ** 2)
    xx = np.exp(-gamma * ssm_xx)
    xy = np.exp(-gamma * ssm_xy)
    yy = np.exp(-gamma * ssm_yy)
    return np.mean(xx - (2.0 * xy) + yy)
```

**My questions are**:

1. Is the above implementation correct? Also, is there any benchmark to validate this implementation?
2. I see that in FID and MMD implementation, the samples are transformed (known as embeddings) before evaluating the MMD, which I am not doing at the moment. Is it necessary to do such a transformation or what is its purpose?
3. If such a transformation is necessary, what are the alternatives for point kind of data?